# Downloading iPhone 4s Simulator on Xcode 11

Tags: xcode

I want to download the simulator of iPhone 4s on Xcode Version 11.2.1. But, as I try to add the simulator for iPhone 4s it say ("Donwload more Simulator runtimes..."). Which OS version Simulator shall I download for iPhone 4s on Xcode 11. Thanks for the help!